# Perl: Exporting functions from a package which is in a subdirectory?

Tags: perl

I've simplified my problem down to a small example.  There is something happening that I don't understand with the way importing / exporting functions from packages works.

This code works and I can call greet() from use-myPack.pl.

```
# myPack.pm
package myPack;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = ('greet');

sub greet {
    printf("Hello!\n");
}

1;

# use-myPack.pl
use myPack qw(greet);
greet();

# Output
PS C:\Users\adam> perl .\use-myPack.pl
Hello!
```

However, when I call use-myPack.pl from the parent directory and use the `::` operator to ensure it can still use myPack, it can't find the function called `greet()`.

```
# myPack.pm
package myPack;
require Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = ('greet');

sub greet {
    printf("Hello!\n");
}

1;

# use-myPack.pl
use adam::myPack qw(greet);
greet();

# Output
PS C:\Users> perl .\adam\use-myPack.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::greet called at .\adam\use-myPack.pl line 2.
```

Can anyone help explain why I can call `greet()` in the first case, but not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name used in the `use` directive must match the package named used in the module's `package` directive (because you end up doing `PACKAGE_NAME->import(IMPORT_LIST)`).

```
use Foo::Bar;     with     package Foo::Bar;     = ok
use Bar;          with     package Foo::Bar;     = not ok
use Foo::Bar;     with     package Bar;          = not ok
```

---

The simplest option is to change the module to use

```
package adam::myPack;
```

to allow you to keep using

```
use adam::myPack qw( greet );
```

---

Otherwise, you need to switch to

```
use myPack qw( greet );
```

and make Perl find the module by changing the library search path (`@INC`) by using

```
use lib 'adam';
```

or

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/adam";
```

The former works if the cwd is different than the scripts directory, while the latter doesn't.

---

### Alternatives to `use lib`

If you called the directory `lib` instead of `adam`, you could use

```
use mylib;  # Short for something similar to:
            #   use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
            #   use lib "$RealBin/lib", "$RealBin/../lib";
```

Or if you have a directory to which you install module for all your scripts (e.g. `~/perl5/lib`), set the environment variable `PERL5LIB` to it in your login script.

```
export PERL5LIB=~/perl5/lib     # sh & bash syntax
```

Comment: Interesting - so is the :: operator (I don't even know what it's called) generally poor practice when "use"ing packages?

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I guess what I'm confused by is the fact that this code *does* work:

`use File::Temp qw(tempfile tempdir);`

Why would it not work for my modules but work for that one?

By the way, I didn't downvote you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Moved my reply to your comments into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mini-tutorial about the differences between [*packages*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) and [*modules*](http://p3rl.org/perlmod).

---

```
use My::Package 1.0 (qw'some options');
#                  ↑ no comma
```

[is effectively the same as:](http://p3l.org/use)

```
BEGIN{
  # load the <module> if it isn't loaded already
  require My::Package;
  # or
  require 'My/Package.pm';



  # check the version of the <package>
  'My::Package'->VERSION(1.0); # compare against $My::Package::VERSION

  # do extra processing in the <package>
  'My::Package'->import(qw'some options');
}
```

Notice that only [`require`](http://p3l.org/use) dealt with the [*module*](http://p3rl.org/perlmod), the rest of the statements all dealt with the [*package*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) of the same name.

#### My/Package.pm:

```
package My::Package;
use strict;
use warnings;

our $VERSION = 1.0; # checked by UNIVERSAL::VERSION
# you can actually override VERSION. ( don't though )

# bad example of an import method
sub import{ # called by C<use>
  my( $package, $filename, $line ) = caller;
  print 'you called ', __PACKAGE__, " from $filename at line $line with options @_\n";

  # the following is similar to how Exporter::import works
  no strict 'refs';
  *{ $package.'::exported_sub' } = \&My::Package::Subs::exported_sub;
}

package My::Package::Subs; # <== look another package in the same module

sub exported_sub{...}
```

---

If you call [`use`](http://p3l.org/use) with an empty list then `import` is not called.

```
use My::Package ();
```

```
BEGIN{
  require 'My/Package.pm';
}
```

The main reason you would do this is to make sure that the [*module*](http://p3rl.org/perlmod) is loaded at compile time without it doing anything extra on behalf of the calling [*package*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages).

---

When you do this:

```
require Exporter; # loads module named Exporter
@ISA = qw(Exporter); # inherit C<import> from Exporter.
```

Any method calls to `import` on the [*package*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) will be handled by `import` in [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html). This includes any [`use`](http://p3l.org/use) statements.
Provided of course that you don't override it by defining your own `import` or `AUTOLOAD` methods.

---

- [*modules*](http://p3rl.org/perlmod) contain **0 or more** [`package`](http://p3rl.org/package) statements.
  Without a [`package`](http://p3rl.org/package) statement, it will be in the same [*package*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) where it was first loaded from.
- A [*module*](http://p3rl.org/perlmod) **usually** contains a [*package*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages) of the same name.

---

As an aside

`::` is **not** an [operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop) (otherwise it would be in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop)).
[Instead `::` and `'` are called package separators.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Packages)

If `::` were an operator, you would be able to do `A :: B :: C` and `A::(B::C)`, which are (currently) syntax errors.